# React native with axios fetch first post delayed

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using react native, and axios.
I have two parts.

1. The exercice list that is rendered with `useEffect` in a div. Inside, there is a Input form which once pressed the `Add set` button, the set is added to the database and the exercices are fetched again with the passed function.
2. The main problem is that when I first add an exercice, the exercice s not rendering. I must go back and come again in the page to render the first one. after doing this process I can add as many exercices... And with delete is same. I can delete any exercice but when deleting the last one, it persist and I must leave the page to see the changes...

THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT ADD THE exercices. It executes once the alert button is pressed

```
const NewExercice = ({dayID, getAllEx}) => {

    // States and ontext change functions
    const [exName, setexName] = useState('');
    const [comment, setcomment] = useState('');
    const handleExname = text => setexName(text);
    const handleComments = text => setcomment(text);

    // Add new exercices
    const handleNewExercice = async () => {
        try 
        {
            const status = await data.post('/api/create-exercice', {dayID, exName, comments: comment});
            Alert.alert(
                'Exercice created',
                'Please add new sets to existing exercices', 
                [
                    {
                        text: 'Ok!',
                        // Fetch again for all the exercices
                        onPress: getAllEx
                    }
                ]
            )
        } 
        
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Bellow is the component that adds map over the array state

```
<View>
                {error ? (<Text>No exercices created yet.</Text>) : 
                exArray.map(obj => (
                    <ExerciceWrapper getAllEx={getAllExercices} navigation={navigation} key={obj.exID} object={obj} />
                ))}
            </View>
```

Bellow is the function that fetch the data from the DB and set the state to be able to be rendered in the component above

```
const getAllExercices = async () => {
        try 
        {
            const response = await data.get('/api/get-all-ex/' + dayID);
            setExArray(response.data);
        } 
        
        catch (error) 
        {
            if (error.response.status === 404) return setError(true);
            else return console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllExercices();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the error value when you have successful fetch as well

update code to this

```
const getAllExercices = async () => {
    try 
    {
        const response = await data.get('/api/get-all-ex/' + dayID);
        setExArray(response.data);
        setError(response.data.length < 1)
    } 
    
    catch (error) 
    {
        if (error.response.status === 404) return setError(true);
        else return console.log(error);
    }
}
```